# Hyperledger Composer - web application authorization using business network card

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a web app which uses a business network model to read from the blockchain and display the assets + execute transactions.

I have already defined my ACL file. Using the playground, as admin, I can create new ID cards and then use these cards to restrict the access in transactions and assets to participants, but how can I associate these ID cards to my web application so the users can see only what they are allowed to see?

I used the [generator-hyperledger-composer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-hyperledger-composer) to generate my angular project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use REST services from your application. Your angular project can connect to the REST server.

Set up REST server authentication and choose a Passport-based authentication mechanism/strategy that best suits your setup -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html and configure REST server multi-user mode -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser

The latter shows how (given that you've created business network cards that contain a user's blockchain identity) you can configure multi-user mode and interact witih the REST server - using a browser and Wallet in this example.

Info on deploying a REST server is here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server